# The requested URL was not found on this server in vps contabo server

Tags: .htaccess, server

I have a problem with the following site `https://973.bio/login`
get the error

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried a lot to solve it but I couldn't.
I am using Contabo vps server
Is there a way to solve?

`.htaccess` file, but I don't know if the code inside it is correct.

Comment: Sorry, with no code we can't help

Comment: ...and with a clear description of what you are actually trying to do with this URL.